# Simplifying two jQuery functions for changing background of two separate dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the background colors of two dropdowns. Inside of these dropdowns have a true or false option. If 'True' is selected, the background color of the dropdown should change to green. If False, the background is red.

At the moment, I have created two separate functions for both of the dropdowns and I'm struggling to find a way to combine both of them without having to use the same id.

```js
$('#dropdown-a').on('change', function(){
   if ($('#dropdown-a option:selected').text() == "True")
      $('#dropdown-a').css('background-color', '#28a745')
   else if ($('#dropdown-a option:selected').text() == "False")
      $('#dropdown-a').css('background-color', '#dc3545')
   else
      $('#dropdown-a').css('background-color', '#dc3545')
});

$('#dropdown-b').on('change', function(){
   if ($('#dropdown-b option:selected').text() == "True")
      $('#dropdown-b').css('background-color', '#28a745')
   else if ($('#dropdown-a option:selected').text() == "False")
      $('#dropdown-b').css('background-color', '#dc3545')
   else
      $('#dropdown-b').css('background-color', '#dc3545')
});
```

```css
 select option[value="True"] {
   background-color: #28a745;
 }

 select option[value="False"] {
   background-color: #dc3545;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form control form-control-sm" id="dropdown-a">
  <option selected disabled value="">True/False</option>
  <option value="True">True</option>
  <option value="False">False</option>
</select>

<select class="form control form-control-sm" id="dropdown-b">
  <option selected disabled value="">True/False</option>
  <option value="True">True</option>
  <option value="False">False</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
const makeDropDown = function(ddSelector){
    $(ddSelector).on('change', function(){
       if ($(ddSelector +' option:selected').text() == "True")
          $(ddSelector).css('background-color', '#28a745')
       else if ($(ddSelector + ' option:selected').text() == "False")
          $(ddSelector).css('background-color', '#dc3545')
       else
          $(ddSelector).css('background-color', '#dc3545')
    });
};
makeDropDown('#dropdown-a');
makeDropDown('#dropdown-b');
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a class instead of an id:

```js
$('.dropdown').on('change', function(){
   if ($(this).find('option:selected').text() == "True")
      $(this).css('background-color', '#28a745')
   else if ($(this).find('option:selected').text() == "False")
      $(this).css('background-color', '#dc3545')
   else
      $(this).css('background-color', '#dc3545')
});
```

```css
 select option[value="True"] {
   background-color: #28a745;
 }

 select option[value="False"] {
   background-color: #dc3545;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form control form-control-sm dropdown" id="dropdown-a">
  <option selected disabled value="">True/False</option>
  <option value="True">True</option>
  <option value="False">False</option>
</select>

<select class="form control form-control-sm dropdown" id="dropdown-b">
  <option selected disabled value="">True/False</option>
  <option value="True">True</option>
  <option value="False">False</option>
</select>
```